# Do games/DLC downloaded on one account show in the history of another account?

Tags: ps3

Would the games/DLC downloaded on one account go onto another accounts (on the same PS3) history?

There's some stuff I didn't buy - my brother may have logged into my account and bought it, or he bought it through his account but it's also showing up in my history.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about [this download history](https://support.us.playstation.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/488/~/redownload-playstation-store-content-on-ps3), I believe that should only show the most recent downloads from your particular account.

However, there is a separate "Purchase History" that you can access from the Account Management in the Playstation Store. This only shows items that were purchased on your account.

Alternatively, you can log in via the web interface (http://us.playstation.com/psn/signin), go to My Account, and click PSN Store Purchase History to view all purchases made from your account.